# Get/load dynamic DIV content from an external website

Tags: php, dom

I'm trying to extract a piece of content (a string of 8 characters) from a public service website and display it on my own website. The public service (PS) website allows re-use of content so no trouble there.

The string I'm trying to extract from the PS website is located inside a `div`. When I select that particular part of the content in my web browser and request the DOM source of the selection, I get:

```
<div class="last-license-plate-truck">8426-STS</div>
```

So extracting that would be very easy using a jQuery or PHP script targeting the `div` class... *but it doesn't work*. My script always returns an empty string when probing *this* particular `div`. Probing other divs on the same page however returns content perfectly fine so the script I'm using works ok.

I found out that if I load the PS website in my browser and then request the page source code without selecting any text first, I get:

```
<div class="last-license-plate-truck"></div>
```

So in the source code the `div` is empty but the browser still displays the last license plate when I visit the PS website.. I suspect the last license plate information is injected dynamically into the `div` by JavaScript or something after the page finished loading.

**Is there any way to still extract the content of that particular `div`?** 
I figure it must be possible somehow since the character string I'm after appears to be present in the DOM?

EDIT - my code below:

```
    <?php
    $host = 'example.com';

    if($socket =@ fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 5)) {

        fclose($socket);

        $last_plate = array(
            "https://www.example.com/page1"=>"car",
            "https://www.example.com/page2"=>"truck",
        );

        foreach($last_plate as $url => $keyword) {

            $page = file_get_contents($url);
            $doc = new DOMDocument();
            libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
            $doc->loadHTML($page);
            libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
            $divs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');

            $found = array($keyword => "notfound");

            foreach($divs as $div) {

                if ($div->getAttribute('class') === 'last-license-plate-'.$keyword) {

                    $found[$keyword] = "found";

                    $cleaned = preg_replace ('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+/', '', $div->nodeValue);

                    $cleaned = str_replace(array("\r", "\n", ' '), '', $cleaned);
                }

            }

            if($found[$keyword] != "found") {

                echo '<p>The last license plate was not found.</p>'."\n";

            }else{

                echo '<p>The last license plate is: '.$cleaned.'</p>'."\n";

            }

        }

    }else{
        echo '<p>Sorry, please try again later.</p>';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Probs we'd need to see some source code showing how you're trying to select it. When you run an `$.ajax` command, it will execute any javascript it finds. I don't know what View source does in the browser, and don't know how you're attempting to retrieve the value.

Comment: If you're lucky, they'll fetch that license plate via a server call in their JS code or something like that and you can then maybe extract that endpoint and hit it yourself? I don't think there is another option (not sure) since their page loads that value every time it loads itself (every time you fetch the page, so checking every second wouldn't be an option). Maybe load it in an 1x1 iframe, wait for dynamic content and then try to fetch it via a DOM selector there.

Comment: @BertMaurau unfortunately the endpoint is hidden so I cannot hit it myself. The 1x1 `iframe` option crossed my mind as well but I think the Same Origin policy will kick in immediately because that would essentially be cross-site scripting, no?

Comment: You already extract the content of that div, it is just that the div is empty. Place a DOM break point with your browsers' developer tools that halts when the div content is changed and then inspect the script traces where the original data comes from. The network utilities there could be also of help learning more. Maybe you don't need to parse the HTML website but just some JSON result of a XHR request.

Comment: @hakre Thanks! Your comment was actually the solution to my problem. Shame I cannot mark it as such. I extracted the endpoint url as per your suggested method (browser dev tools > Network > filter JS and XHR) and was able (and allowed by the content-security-policy) to hit it myself. It provided me with a nice JSON response which I could perfectly integrate. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see @hakre 's comment above. It provided the answer to my question.

A little background on how:
It tuned out that my original idea of parsing the whole page and looking for the content of a particular `div` could be simplified. I loaded the public service website in question in my browser and opened the developer toolkit (F12); navigated to the tab "Network", reloaded the page and applied the filters to only sniff JS and XHR traffic. From there I was able to extract the endpoint URL responsible for dynamically loading the content of the `<div class="last-license-plate-truck"></div>` div. It turned out the endpoint (REST API) responded with a nice JSON format which I could easily grab using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

use `innerText` instead of `nodeValue`.

Replace following line

```
$cleaned = preg_replace ('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+/', '', $div->nodeValue);
```

with

```
$cleaned = preg_replace ('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+/', '', $div->innerText);
```

Comment: if I use `$div->innerText` it throws me an error: Undefined property: DOMElement::$innerText. `$div->nodeValue` and `$div->textContent` do somehow not result in this error (but don't produce results either).